# Parameretrize file descriptor number to open a tcp socket in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, io-redirection, file-descriptors

I'm tried to parameretrize in a variable the file descriptor number to open a tcp socket using exec command but it failed. Only work correctly when file descriptor number is a constant. In the next example code only success the first retry (RC=0).

Code:

```
echo -e "\nRetry 1: "
socket="/dev/tcp/$ip/$port"
exec 3<>$socket
echo "RC: $?"


echo -e "\nRetry 2: "
descriptor=3
socket="/dev/tcp/$ip/$port"
exec $descriptor<>$socket
echo "RC: $?"


echo -e "\nRetry 3: "
descriptor="3"
socket="/dev/tcp/$ip/$port"
exec $descriptor<>$socket
echo "RC: $?"

echo -e "\nRetry 4: "
descriptor=3
socket="/dev/tcp/$ip/$port"
exec "$descriptor"<>$socket
echo "RC: $?"

echo -e "\nRetry 5: "
descriptor=3
socket="/dev/tcp/$ip/$port"
`exec $descriptor<>$socket`
echo "RC: $?"
```

The output is:

```
Retry 1:
RC: 0

Retry 5:
socket.sh: line 46: exec: 3: not found
RC: 127
```

or, in other cases:

```
Retry 1:
RC: 0

Retry X:
socket.sh: line 27: exec: 3: not found
```

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to understand why it fails when you think of:

```
echo $text>some-file
```

You wouldn't want it to behave differently if `$text` happens to contain a number.

You'd need to use `eval` here:

```
eval 'exec '"$fd"'> "$file"'
```

(you want `$fd` to be expanded in the arguments to `eval`, but not `$file`).

Note that ksh93, zsh and bash have introduced (in April 2005, zsh 4.3.0, bash 4.1-alpha, ksh93r) the possibility to have dynamic fds, like:

```
exec {fd}> "$file"
```

Here, the file descriptor (a free one above 10) is chosen by the shell and stored into the `$fd` variable.

Which you can use with `... >&$fd`.

It matches more closely what you do in other languages: `fd = open(...)`, `write(fd, ...)`.

Comment: Thanks you @sch . The eval solution works fine but the dinamyc file descriptor solution fails: **exec: {fd}: not found**. The bash version is: GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: Yes, it is relatively recent (7 years), I've edited my answer. See also this [thread on the zsh ML](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.zsh.user/11673/focus=11688)